# c++ tiny-js execute javascript function from external file

Tags: javascript, c++, pac

I have a C++ application which has to execute a Javascript-function from a dynamic file. (I need to read a proxy.pac file).

E.g. I have a C++ application running which reads the following file: proxy.pac (which contains the javascript function `FindProxyForURL(url, host)`, which I have to call with the two parameters.

However, I have no idea how to start off and I can't find anything on the internet so far.

***So basically my question is: how doe I load dynamic Javascript from a file and execute a function within that code(/file)***

Answer (score 0):

I made application server using TinyJS.
see this.
https://github.com/pochi0701/wizdlive